# how to extract value from the tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how to extract selectd value from the "txt" data

from below tag I am expecting "440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle"

```
txt = '[<select class="bg21" name="cyfbh" style="WIDTH: 100%"><option value=""></option> <option value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option> <option selected="" value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select>]'
datatag =str(txt) 

print datatag


soup = BeautifulSoup(datatag,'lxml')
text_area = soup.find('option', {'selected':'selected'} )

print text_area
```

when I tried above code I am getting None

Comment: First of all, your syntax is a bit all over the place... You do not need to define txt as a string, as it already is.

Secondly, within the string, are brackets - which would denote a list.

Are you trying to simulate an XML scraped from the web? Or JSON?

Comment: @Marc Leonard  I am trying to simulate xml scraped from web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `.text` like :

```
text_area = soup.find('option', {'selected':'selected'} ).text
```

**EDIT:**

i made a mistake of not running the code and assumed there will be no mistakes in find. anyways, this code below ran and it works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '[<select class="bg21" name="cyfbh" style="WIDTH: 100%"><option value=""></option> <option value="440615000101">440615000101-passenger car</option> <option selected="" value="440615000102">440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle</option></select>]'

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt,'html.parser')
text_area = soup.find('option', {'value':'440615000102'}).text
print(text_area)
```

i used python standard parser "html.parser", difference with lxml is its speed according to [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

**o/p:**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCquY.jpg)

Comment: this fiter will return None, have you test your code?

Comment: if you are asking whether i have tested `.text` , then Yes. i have tested and used it before. it worked for me. but i guess the exact line which i gave above is not working since i assumed arguments inside find is correct(didn't bother to check it). my bad. i'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
text_area = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='option' and tag.has_attr('selected') )
```

out:

```
440615000102-two/three wheeled motorcycle
```

use `has_attr` to find tag, the tag's `selected` value is `''`, an empty string, and BS4 can not find it by using:

```
soup.find('option', {'selected':''} )
```